# Modeling a Top in Makie.jl

Tags: coordinate-transformation, makie.jl

I am currently doing a project where I am modeling a top. My question is how to display the "attitude" of the top onto a makie axis3 object.

Question: Given the local coordinate frame of a mesh, how to apply it to the mesh in Makie.jl

Note: The frame is not translating

I have looked at the documentation of Makie and there exists something called Model for mesh objects. I probably have to use this, just wondering if anyone has used it before and knows how to relate coordinate transformations to this object.